# convert linq to lambda with multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to convert this linq query to lambda

```
 var query = (from a in context.Table_A
                         join u in context.Table_B  on a.scored equals u.userid
                         join u2 in context.Table_B on a.scorer equals u2.userid
                         from cs in a.Table_C //(Table_A is related to Table_C)
                         where (a.date>= startdate && a.date < enddate)
                         select new MSViewModel
                         {
                             scored= u.User.name,
                             scorer= u2.User.name,
                             subject_name = cs.Subject.name,
                             score = cs.score,
                             categoryid = cs.id,
                         })
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(t => t.scored)
                            .ToList();
```

so far this is what i have. I'm kinda lost what to do next.

```
 var tobi = db.Table_A.Join(db.Table_B,a=>a.scored,u=>u.userid,
                    (a,u) => new {scored=u.User.name });
                    db.Table_A.Join(db.Table_B,a1=>a1.scorer,u2=>u2.userid, 
                    (a,u2)=> new {scorer= u2.User.name});
```

Comment: Why? I personally think the later is a hell of a lot harder to read.

Comment: Yeah but it's my requirement, I've no say in it

Comment: @deidarasong: Push back. It's a *stupid* requirement, and you have my permission to pass that on verbatim to your TL or whoever :)

Comment: If you have Resharper, it will give you an option to convert LINQ to Lambada...

Comment: @deidarasong: remember that `Jon Skeet` told you :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, I'd agree with Arran's comment: the query expression is going to be much simpler to deal with. I'm absolutely on board with using the lambda form where it makes sense, but joins are generally *much* simpler in query expressions.

Having said that, you basically need to imitate [transparent identifiers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2006/12/22/transparent-identifiers.aspx). The code below is untested, but looks vaguely plausible to me.

```
var query = context.Table_A
                   .Join(context.Table_B, a => a.scored, u => u.userid,
                         (a, u) => new { a, u })
                   .Join(context.Table_B, p => p.a.scorer, u2 => u2.userid,
                         (p, u2) => new { p, u2 })
                   .SelectMany(q => q.p.a.TableC, (q, cs) => new { q, cs })
                   .Where(r => r.q.p.a.date >= startdate && r.q.p.a.date < enddate)
                   .Select(q => new MSViewModel {
                                  scored= r.q.p.u.User.name,
                                  scorer= r.q.u2.User.name,
                                  subject_name = r.cs.Subject.name,
                                  score = r.cs.score,
                                  categoryid = r.cs.id,
                                })
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(t => t.scored)
                   .ToList();
```

Basically `p` and `q` and `r` are the transparent identifiers here. You've got three of them because you've got two joins and a subsequent `from` clause.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment, If you have Resharper:

**Resharper showing option to convert LINQ to Lambada**
[image]

**After the conversion:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
    var query = (_context.Table_A.Join(_context.Table_B, a => a.scored, u =>
    u.userid,
    (a, u) => new {a, u}).Join(_context.Table_B,
    @t => @t.a.scorer,
    u2 => u2.userid,
    (@t, u2) => new {@t, u2}).
    SelectMany(@t => _context.Table_A, (@t, cs) => new MSViewModel()
    {
    scored = @t.@t.u.User.name,
    scorer= @t.u2.User.name,
    subject_name = @t.cs.Subject.name,
    score = @t.cs.score,
    categoryid = @t.cs.id,
    })).AsEnumerable()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You're missing a Where call, which is why three transparent identifiers are needed instead of two.